# Mockito Mocking any I18n instance created runtime

Tags: java, mockito

I have a scenario ,like i am creating i18n object instance dynamically in code. I am using the following code:

```
public String getLocaleString(Locale locale, SlingHttpServletRequest request){
    final ResourceBundle bundle = request.getResourceBundle(locale);
    I18n i18n = new I18n(bundle);
    return i18n.get("local");
}
```

Here locale, request I have mocked.  But i18n is created dynamically. so am not able to mock `i18n.get("local")`.

I tried using:

```
when(any(I18n.class).get("local")).thenReturn("localizedString")
```

But I am not able to. I am getting NullPointerException in this line.

I would like to use Mockito for mocking this scenario. Can you guys help me please? Thanks.

Comment: What does `I18n` do when you call `get` on it?

Answer (score 2):

Mockito has suggesting refactoring to get around this https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation?ts=1332544670&updated=MockingObjectCreation

I normally avoid testing internals of the method.

But in some cases when I really need I use PowerMockito https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor

Comment: Yeah don't test the internal of the method, it makes test brittle ! Instead test the resulting behavior of the method given some input. Also remember mocks aren't always the best option to make sure your code works, sometime testing with real objects is the best way to assert the behavior of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to use `any()` in that way, as it's an argument matcher, you should only specify a `mock` object with a method invocation, e.g.:

```
when(mock(i18n).get("local")).thenReturn("localizedString");
```

I think that might be the source of your `NullPointerException`.

But to solve your problem, I think you have two options:

The first is to use a factory to create the `I18n` object, and then mock the factory:

```
...
private I18nFactory factory;
...

public String getLocaleString(Locale locale, SlingHttpServletRequest request){
    final ResourceBundle bundle = request.getResourceBundle(locale);
    I18n i18n = factory.get(bundle);
    return i18n.get("local");
}
```

Then in your test, set up the factory to produce the object you want:

```
// Mock I18n, locale, request etc...

final I18nFactory factory = mock(I18nFactory.class);
when(factory.get(bundle)).thenReturn(i81n);

// Assign 'factory' to your Controller(?)
controller.setI18nFactory(factory);

// act, assert etc...
```

The second approach is to set up the `locale` and `request` mocks/objects in such a way that `new I18n(...)` creates a valid object which meets your expectations.

On balance, I think I would prefer to use the second approach, especially so if `I18n` is a 3rd-party class. Although without more information on the aim of your test, this answer is somewhat speculative. Anyway, I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi,

The issue is resolved.

The main problem was the key is not available in ResourceBundle.

So instead of giving mocked resource bundle, i have created a resourceBundle instance using the Resource object with necessary key and values. After that i passed resourceBundle instance to the method.

It worked. Thanks alot for your guidance.